# Using polymorphism to copy derived class' value to the base class

Tags: c++, class

English is not my first language. I hope I will not make lot of mistakes. I'll try my best to be as clear as possible!

I have a base class

```
class engine
{
private :
    std::string name;
    double weight;

public:
    engine();
    ~engine();
    std::string getName() const;
    int getWeight() const
};

std::string engine::getName() const{
return this->name;
}

int engine::getWeight() const{
return this->weight;
}
```

and derived class

```
class diesel : public engine
{
private:
    std::string name;
    double weight;

public:
    diesel();
    ~diesel();
};

diesel::diesel(){
this->name = Diesel;
this->weight = 500.00;
}
```

In my main.cpp

```
int main()
{
      diesel diesel_engine; 
      const engine &e = diesel_engine;
      std::cout<<e.getWeight()<<e.getName()<<std::endl;
      return 0;
}
```

1- I must construct a diesel class named diesel_engine.

2- pass diesel_engine's value to a new engine by reference??

When I call `const engine &e = diesel_engine;`, diesel_engine's value(name and weight) should  be copied to the new engine e.

So 'e' should have weight of 500.00 and the name "Diesel".

I don't get how can I use polymorphism to do that.

Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: It would be great it would add class declarations.

Comment: okay I will! thank you

Comment: not quite sure if I really understand; seems like the member variables `name` and `weight` should have the `protected` modifier, then. and not be redeclared in the derived class. what happens? do you get a compile-time error, runtime error, how do you check the value of `engine` at the end of your `main`?

Comment: "When I call const engine &e = diesel_engine;, diesel_engine's value(name and weight) should be copied to the new engine e." - `e` is a *reference*, not a new object, nothing is being copied.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was confused because when I call const engine &e = diesel_engine, am I not make a new engine?

Comment: @신한슬 No. You are *not* making a new engine. You are making a *reference* (the`&`) to an existing engine.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you so much for your answer! Jesper! have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the class declarations

```
class Engine
{
private:
    float weight_;
    std::string name_;
public:
    Engine(float weight, std::string name) : weight_(weight), name_(name){};
    std::string GetName() const { return name_;}
};

class Diesel : public Engine
{
public:
  Diesel(float weight, std::string name) : Engine(weight, name){} 
};
```

So what we have here is an `Engine` class which is our `base class` and then we define our `Diesel class`, `Diesel` inherits from `Engine` and passes the arguments to its base class.

Now to use this:

```
Diesel disel_engine(0.0, "diesel engine");
const Engine& eng = disel_engine;
cout << eng.GetName();
```

The call to `eng.GetName()` prints the correct engine name

[Demo Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/736978e45dd761dc)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering to my question! Now I understand how to use it ! Thanx again!

Comment: I do recommend getting a good C++ book and also fully understand why this works.